# xsl:sort an XML file using 2 different nodes

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to sort a list of stores first by province then by town.  Here's a sample xml:

```
 <store>
  <name>Duncan's</name>
  <town>Waterloo</town>
  <province>Ontario</province>
 </store>
 <store>
  <name>Anne's</name>
  <town>Waterloo</town>
  <province>Ontario</province>
 </store>
 <store>
  <name>Apple Variety</name>
  <town>Woodstock</town>
  <province>Ontario</province>
 </store>
 <store>
  <name>Goose Market</name>
  <town>Sackville</town>
  <province>New Brunswick</province>
 </store>
 <store>
  <name>Family Market</name>
  <town>Sackville</town>
  <province>New Brunswick</province>
 </store>
```

I was able to successfully sort the data by town using this code:

```
  <xsl:key name="towns" match="store" use="town"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="//store[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('towns', town)[1])]">
 <xsl:sort select="town"/> 
    <xsl:for-each select="key('towns', town)">
      <xsl:sort select="name"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <h2>
              <xsl:value-of select="town"/>
            </h2>
      </xsl:if>
     <b> <xsl:value-of select="name"/></b> <br/>

     <br/> <br/>      
     </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
```

How would I use a key to first sort by Province, listing all the stores in New Brunswick (alphabetically first by town then by name) then Ontario?  Or is there a better way to do this without using a key? Thanks!

Comment: You say you are *sorting*, but you are also *grouping*. It's not clear if you want to also group by province or just sort by it. You can sort without a key, but you do need it in order to group.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to group as well as sort. So, first group and sort by province, then group and sort by town name (within those province groups) then finally sort by store name (within those town groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> first group and sort by province, then group and sort by town name
>   (within those province groups) then finally sort by store name (within
>   those town groups)

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="province" match="store" use="province"/>
<xsl:key name="town" match="store" use="concat(province, '|', town)"/>

<xsl:template match="/stores">
    <xsl:for-each select="store[generate-id()=generate-id(key('province', province)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="province"/> 
        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="province"/>
        </h2>

        <xsl:for-each select="key('province', province)[generate-id()=generate-id(key('town', concat(province, '|', town))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="town"/>
            <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="town"/>
            </h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('town', concat(province, '|', town))">
                <xsl:sort select="name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the assumed `stores` root element.

Answer (score 0):

Use two xsl:sort elements for the primary and secondary keys, respectively.